# Does Viber app have a menu to close the app?

Tags: viber-messenger

I would like to use Viber only if I need it. I want to turn it off if I do not use it, regardless if I can be reached or not.

I do not wish to have a program running and using energy all the time. However, I can't seem to find any close menu to kill the app. Does it even have a close menu / function?

Comment: The title of your question seems to be unrelated to the main body. Are you asking about the menu, or about how to only run Viber some of the time? What phone are you using?

Comment: @DanHulme I think it's better to rephrase the question so that it's on topic. To summarize, he wants a way to close Viber, but he can't find the menu for it.

Comment: Rephrased the question to prevent it from closing.

Comment: I am using a Samsung GT-S5301.   I would like to see the menu on the Viber app. How can I only run Viber some of the time? And am I able to close the app?       Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just installed Viber on my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2), and I can find an exit menu via `More Options > Exit`.

[image]